# Cant pass data from android to php file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

My android code is:

```
String name1="xxx"; String place1="yyy";
        String result=null;
        URL url=null;
        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try {
           String data = URLEncoder.encode("event", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name1, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("city", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(place1, "UTF-8");

        url = new URL("http://mytechnologies.com/events/getdetails.php");

        // Send POST data request
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput (true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "mytechnologies.com");
        try{
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();}
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        conn.connect();
```

And my php code is:

```
$title = $_POST['event'];
$place = $_POST['city'];
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event where place='$place' and title='$title'");
```

The data is not passed to php file. Have given internet permission. What is my mistake. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some more information to your question: Do you get any error from the Android code? Try to add some logging to the catch clause of your try-catch statement. Is the URL with your PHP-script actually requested according to the logs of your webserver?

Comment: Im not getting any error. It returns null values from server as the query checks table with null fields

Comment: Why is your content-type header set to `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: yeah that fixed my issue..thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Therefore, PHP does not recognize the body of the POST request as form data.